# select count of each distinct value in a column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to SELECT a result set which contains two columns:

- The DISTINCT values of a column.
- The number of times that that value appears in the column in the table.

This statement (sort of) illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID AS X,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #t WHERE ID = X)
FROM #t
ORDER BY X;
```

The desired result set would look like:

```
| ID   | COUNT
|------|------
| 0    | 12
| 1    | 16
| 2    | 4
```

Comment: Your query should work too. What is the problem you are getting?

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia . . . The problem would be that the column alias `X` is not defined.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I have edited my answer, based on your input to correct the existing query too.

Comment: don't use a correlated subquery for this, distinct is a "row operator" it has to evaluate uniqueness as the last step, so you are potentially running the subquery many more times then you need to. A simple `group by` is the appropriate method here

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   ID AS X,
         COUNT(*) AS "COUNT"
FROM     #t
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY X
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple agregation using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*)
FROM #t
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   ID AS X,
         COUNT(1) AS "COUNT"
FROM     #t
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Use [Group By](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php)

Your query (Correlated subqueries) should work too. As per GordonLinoff, Replace X with ID in your query and it should work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID AS X,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #t WHERE ID = X)
FROM #t
ORDER BY ID ;
```